# ER model of school system

Tags: entity-relationship

There are four requirement!
There are schools, students, and clubs.

1. Every student attends one and only one school; every school has more than one student.
2. Every student may optionally join one club; every club has more than one student.
3. Every club belongs to one school; some schools have more than one club,
   some schools have none.
4. Any student may work as an assistants for only one school; every
   school may have one assistant at most.

How to draw the 4th requirement in my [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAcUo.jpg)

Comment: Add formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It's called relation you will insert a middle relation. So for example

(student)0,1 ---> (assistant) <----0,1(School)

So the trick is to create a new entity. And you throw those relation. A student may be or not be an assistant (0,1 means that) and a school may have or not have one assistant.